# sound device bag back support

Tags: cases, device

Hey guys I have a sound device case like this one

http://www.sounddevices.com/products/cs3/
[image]

I was wondering if I could get some advice, I added a strap to go around my waist so I do not get back issues by hanging it over my shoulders. It is just that I am now getting back issues because of the strap. So I was wondering if anyone could give me some pointers to make it more effective.

Thank you so much.
Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

Besides having a proper setup (the right gear and the right usage), you should also look into getting exercises for your shoulders and back. I've been having serious issues for years after occasionally booming but mainly by having 'weak' shoulders and neglecting to do something about that. I can also totally recommend going to a physician/doctor specialized in the shoulder/back, explain your goals and issues clearly.

Good luck!
Arnoud

Answer (score 1):

Petrol makes an awesome bag system, and they have an optional harness that you can purchase to use with it. Highly recommended.